# How do I calculate a rolling mean with custom weights in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

The Pandas documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html has an example of how to calculate moving averages:

```
ser = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=10))
pd.rolling_window(ser, 5, 'boxcar')
```

The second line calculates a rolling average with a window of 5 and equal weights on each of the five observations. The docs refer tantalizingly to the possibility of using custom weights ("When passing a win_type instead of explicitly specifying the weights..."), but how do you do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not Math expert, but *stahlous* explain what you need [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8238#issuecomment-56139375).

I try test it:

```
import pandas as pd

ser = pd.Series([1,1,1], index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=3))
print ser

rm1 = pd.rolling_window(ser, window=[2,2,2], mean=False)
rm2 = pd.rolling_window(ser, window=[2,2,2]) #, mean=True

print rm1
#
#2000-01-01   NaN
#2000-01-02   NaN
#2000-01-03     6
#Freq: D, dtype: float64
print rm2
#
#2000-01-01   NaN
#2000-01-02   NaN
#2000-01-03     1
#Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

I setting `window` to `ndarray` (`[2,2,2]`) and calculated weighted sum (`rm1`) and weighted mean (`rm2`).

[pandas.rolling_window](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_window.html):

> **window** : *int or ndarray*:
>   Weighting window specification. If the window is an integer, then it is treated as the window length and win_type is required
>
> **mean** : *boolean, default True*
>   If True computes weighted mean, else weighted sum

Comment: How can I do this in pandas 0.20.3 - seems like the method `rolling_window` does not exist anymore and I can't find an alternative.

Comment: @Make42 - I dont know :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all in new pandas versions `rolling` syntaxis had been changed
If you need just triangle window, you can do it like this:

```
ser.rolling(5, win_type='triang').mean()
```

Some other standard windows [are also supported](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html)

If you want really custom (self made) average weights, you can use custom `.apply` and weighted average `np.average` like this

```
import numpy as np

# your code here

weights = [1, 2, 8, 3, 2]  # something unusual
ser.rolling(5).apply(lambda seq: np.average(seq, weights=weights))
```