# rolling_window or rolling_apply in pandas 0.20.3

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use a custom array for weighting valus in a time series / data.frame like in [How do I calculate a rolling mean with custom weights in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368078/how-do-i-calculate-a-rolling-mean-with-custom-weights-in-pandas) like

```
import pandas as pd

ser = pd.Series([1,1,1], index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=3))
print ser

rm1 = pd.rolling_window(ser, window=[2,2,2], mean=False)
rm2 = pd.rolling_window(ser, window=[2,2,2]) #, mean=True

print rm1
#
#2000-01-01   NaN
#2000-01-02   NaN
#2000-01-03     6
#Freq: D, dtype: float64
print rm2
#
#2000-01-01   NaN
#2000-01-02   NaN
#2000-01-03     1
#Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

but it seems this does not exist anymore in pandas 0.20.3. How can I do this?

As it stands, I get the error

> ValueError: window must be an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am particularily interested in an aging with a half Gaussian function. So this seems to work:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import math

def half_gaussian_convolution(input):
    normal_weighting = norm.pdf(np.array(range(-len(input) + 1, 1)), scale=(len(input) - 1) / 1.6448536269514722)
    normal_weighting = normal_weighting / np.sum(normal_weighting)
    return np.sum(normal_weighting * input)

ser.rolling(window=4, center=False).apply(func=half_gaussian_convolution)
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by half Gaussian function, unless you're talking about a half-normal distribution. In any case, your solution appears to slide the weights along the rolling window as well. Is that what you intend?

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr: A normal distribution is a type of distribution that is described by a Gaussian function which has a particular parametrisation. A Gaussian function is a particular function. I meant a function that is 0 for possitive (or negative) values and otherwise like a Gaussian function.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of any simple solution using just the new `rolling` method. It seems that the only way is to create a dataframe and create a new column with the weighted values.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1], index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=3), columns=['value'])
>>> df['weight'] = [2, 2, 2]
>>> df['weighted'] = df['value'] * df['weight']
>>> df
            value  weight  weighted
2000-01-01      1       2         2
2000-01-02      1       2         2
2000-01-03      1       2         2
```

Calculating the sum is pretty straightforward. After creating your dataframe, use the `rolling` method and sum. Using the example you provided, it looks like the window is size of 3.

```
>>> df_rolled = df.rolling(3).sum()
>>> df_rolled['weighted']
2000-01-01    NaN
2000-01-02    NaN
2000-01-03    6.0
Freq: D, Name: weighted, dtype: float64
```

Calculating the weighted mean however will require you to generate another column that calculates the weighted mean where you're taking the values in the *weighted* column and dividing them by the values in the *weight* column. This ensures that you're calculating the weighted mean, not the mean of the weighted values... big difference here.

```
>>> df_rolled['w_mean'] = df_rolled['weighted'] / df_rolled['weight']
>>> df_rolled['w_mean']
2000-01-01    NaN
2000-01-02    NaN
2000-01-03    1.0
Freq: D, Name: w_mean, dtype: float64
```

Another example to check if the solution works, and it does:

```
>>> df['value'] = [2, 4, 6]
>>> df['weight'] = [1, 3, 5]
>>> df['weighted'] = df['value'] * df['weight']
>>> df
            value  weight  weighted
2000-01-01      2       1         2
2000-01-02      4       3        12
2000-01-03      6       5        30
>>> df_rolled = df.rolling(3).sum()
>>> df_rolled['weighted']  # weighted sum
2000-01-01     NaN
2000-01-02     NaN
2000-01-03    44.0
Freq: D, Name: weighted, dtype: float64
>>> df_rolled['w_mean'] = df['weighted'] / df['weight']
>>> df_rolled['w_mean']  # weighted mean
2000-01-01         NaN
2000-01-02         NaN
2000-01-03    4.888889
Freq: D, Name: w_mean, dtype: float64
>>> df_rolled = df.rolling(2).sum()  # window size 2
>>> df_rolled['weighted']
2000-01-01     NaN
2000-01-02    14.0
2000-01-03    42.0
Freq: D, Name: weighted, dtype: float64
>>> df_rolled['w_mean'] = df_rolled['weighted'] / df_rolled['weight']
>>> df_rolled['w_mean']
2000-01-01     NaN
2000-01-02    3.50
2000-01-03    5.25
Freq: D, Name: w_mean, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I might have an answer for my question - what do you think of it?